# Converting an array of promises from Selenium's findElements into an array of objects

Tags: node.js, selenium, q

I am using Selenium with node.js I am trying to do the following

```
var driver   = *webdriver instance*;
var my_xpath = *an xpath string*;
var ele;

Q.all(driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath(my_xpath))).then(function(elements) {
    for (ele in elements) {
        console.log(ele.getText());
    };
}
```

I was under the impression that `Q.all` would convert the array of promises returned by `driver.findElements` into an array of values so that when I output `ele.getText()` it would be a value. However in this case the `ele` is still a promise.

What am I missing here?

Note that I realise that for the above example this is unnecessary and I can simple use a  `ele.getText().then`, but my actual program requires having all the values before proceeding.

Comment: Ok, so I realise why it happens now but don't know how to fix it. `ele.getText()` returns a promise even though `ele` is a `WebElement`. However I still want an array of all the actual outputs as opposed to just promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to aggregate the promises with `all` since `findElements` returns a single promise. You also need to iterate the resolved array with a `for` loop and not a `for-in` loop:

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath(my_xpath)).then(function(elements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text);
        })
    };
});
```

You could also use `map` to directly get an array with the text for each element :

```
var map = webdriver.promise.map;

var elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(my_xpath));

map(elements, e => e.getText()).then(function(texts) {
  console.log(texts);
});
```