# Replace Promise code with Async code plus For loop with map() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, async-await, es6-promise

The following code works just fine. But, I would like to change the Promise code in the middle of the function (indicated by comments) to Async code and replace the for loop with map(). How would I do this?

```
const main = async () => {
    try{
        const driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
            .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
            .setLoggingPrefs(prefs)
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(options)
            .build();

        // Start promise code
        await driver.findElements(By.css('input'))
        .then(function(elements){
            for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
                elements[i].getAttribute("value")
                .then(function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
        // End promise code

        await driver.quit();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

main();
```

Comment: Promises are asynchronous ... you're already using async/await, so it's not that you want to change the code to use async/await ... so ... can't for the life of me guess what it is you want to do

Comment: `elements[i].getAttribute("value").then` well, that looks funky! I take it `elements` are **not** an array of DOM elements

Comment: @JaromandaX code in question is selenium code, not that I know anything about it, but indeed, I doubt `elements` is WebAPI's `Element`. Though I can't find anywhere that this method would return a Promise...

Comment: something like `var elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('input')), values = elements.map(element => element.getAttribute('value'));`
`

Comment: though, I still don't understand why the question asks to make the promise code async ... as promise code is inherently asynchronous

Comment: No, this is selenium webdriver code running in node.js. But it's just JavaScript so I didn't think that would be pertinent.

Comment: When I say async, I'm specifically meaning async/await, not async short for the word asynchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146870/converting-an-array-of-promises-from-seleniums-findelements-into-an-array-of-ob

Comment: Start by using `await` instead of `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're merely dumping information to the console, I'd suggest:

```
// Start promise code
try {
  for (let element of await driver.findElements(By.css('input'))){
    console.log(await element.getAttribute("value"));
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

This shows how `async`/`await` nicely recaptures imperative programming, using `let` in loops.

It differs from your code in that it lists the attributes in order (yours relied on `getAttribute` timing).

If speed is important, get the attributes in parallel while maintaining order like this:

```
let elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('input'));
for (let val of await Promise.all(elements.map(e => e.getAttribute("value")))) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: Both CRice and jib gave me correct answers to my question. I'm giving the answer to jib for giving my multiple solutions, but I tested CRice's answer and it works too so I gave CRice a thumbs up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you want to replace some of that promise code with functionally identical code of a different style? If so, here is that code (dubiously) compressed into two lines:

```
// Start promise code
const elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('input'));
await Promise.all(elements.map(ele => ele.getAttribute('value').then(console.log))).catch(console.log);
// End promise code
```

You mention that you'd like to replace the promise based code with async/await style code. I'd caution against that in general (although in this instance I think it helps), since async/await is based on promises anyway (so there's no escaping them). Learn to love the promise, and only use the async/await syntax when it really makes the code cleaner.